# How to choose other nameserver for qemu VM

Tags: environment-variables, dns, qemu

This question could be more general if use "qemu" as a variable name for application. My host machine is inside a local private network with NAT firewall to Internet. Its IP is, let us say, `192.168.150.22`. There are some other member on the local network like NAS, printer, local www server etc. I configured a simple qemu VM with the most simple `-netdev type=user,...` called SLiRP.
I would like to restrict this VM to local network only to be able to save data to NAS, print to local printer, get info from local www server, but not to go to the Internet for the security reason.

The most simple way I tried to use was to give the VM IP of an other nameserver, which is  configured just for the local net. The dnsmasq seems to be the ideal choice. But I did not find a way how to force the qemu VM to use the other nameserver. There is no parameter/option in the VM configuration, there is no system environment variable suitable for that purpose. While the `dig` command can be forced with the `@12.34.56.78` parameter.

I googled the Internet up'n'down and I did not find any simple solution.

By using the qemu user mode, the installed system has to take its IP and other network parameters from DHCP and it gets also the `nameserver 10.0.2.3`, which is just connected to resolving system of the host.

I tried to use `env HOSTALIAS=` , read plenty of pages describing `NetworkManager`, `resolver`, and so on , etc.

It is evidently question not for qemu only, because I met lot of similar questions, looking for similar feature for testing purposes or VNC etc., for use with other programs.

The most elegant solution seems to me something like the `env variable DNS=x.y.z.j` giving the program special address where to ask for name resolving. Just in the same way as the `env TMPDIR=/pa/th/` do that. The special qemu parameter like `-netdev type=user,usedns=12.34.56.78,....` could be also acceptable.

Does anybody know some simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

In user network mode you can define other range for DNS.
I'm not sure if you can use external DNS.
Check this [link](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking) of qemu about networking.

`-netdev user,id=mynet0,net=192.168.76.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.76.9`